# How would you install OpenSSL package for Ruby?

Tags: ruby, openssl, rvm

I have trouble finding the package for this software. I built and installed from the packages found [here](http://www.openssl.org/), but it's still not working properly with rvm and gem (log is located [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10561853/having-trouble-setting-up-rvm-environment-to-work-with-gist-and-openssl/10564926#10564926)). How would you suggest finding a package for this to work properly?

```
stanley@ubuntu:~/Github/webdev_class/ruby$ sudo apt-cache search ^openssl
[sudo] password for stanley: 
openssl-blacklist - Blacklists for  OpenSSL RSA keys and tools
openssl-blacklist-extra - Non-default blacklists of OpenSSL RSA keys
libengine-pkcs11-openssl - OpenSSL engine for PKCS#11 modules
libxmlsec1-openssl - Openssl engine for the XML security library
openssl - Secure Socket Layer (SSL) binary and related cryptographic tools
```

Here is the printout after trying `dpkg -l | grep openssl`.

```
stanley@ubuntu:~/Github/webdev_class/ruby$ dpkg -l | grep openssl
ii  openssl                                1.0.0e-2ubuntu4.5                       Secure Socket Layer (SSL) binary and related cryptographic tools
ii  python-openssl                         0.12-1ubuntu1                           Python wrapper around the OpenSSL library
```

Comment: Use `dpkg -l | grep openssl` to see if you've got a version of openssl the package manager knows about.

Comment: See my edits. Now trying with more suggestions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `sudo apt-get install openssl`, or use the software center to find it.

[image: Install via the software center]

When I look for packages, I generally use `apt-cache search whatever`.
For openssl, here's what I see on my system:

```
$ apt-cache search ^openssl
openssl - Secure Socket Layer (SSL) binary and related cryptographic tools
openssl-blacklist - Blacklists for  OpenSSL RSA keys and tools
openssl-blacklist-extra - Non-default blacklists of OpenSSL RSA keys
libengine-pkcs11-openssl - OpenSSL engine for PKCS#11 modules
libxmlsec1-openssl - Openssl engine for the XML security library
```

For gem dependencies, you would normally use something like :

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-full build-essential ruby-rvm yorick rubygems
```

However, apparently [ruby-rvm is broken](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9056395/373539), so the ex(?)-maintainer's advice is to remove it completely, and install via the provided URL and bash script:

---

> ```
> sudo apt-get --purge remove ruby-rvm
> sudo rm -rf /usr/share/ruby-rvm /etc/rvmrc /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh
> ```
>
> open new terminal and validate environment is clean from old rvm
>   settings (should be no output):
>
> ```
> env | grep rvm
> ```
>
> if there was output, try to open new terminal, if it does not help -
>   restart computer
>
> install RVM:
>
> ```
> curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
> ```
>
> do not forget to read `rvm requirements` before installing rubies

---

Comment: I've updated my question with your suggestions.

Comment: Ah, see the command I actually ran -- use the `^` in `^openssl` to trim the output.   I don't believe you need sudo for apt-cache (I never do) -- might save you a few keystrokes per year.  I'll update my answer shortly -- waiting to see if this is getting you closer.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistakes. I've updated the log in my question.

Answer (score 4):

OpenSSL is usually installed by default on Ubuntu. You can look up, why it is installed with:

```
aptitiude why package
```

For openssl this can be retraced to cups:

```
$ LANG=C aptitude why openssl
i   ssl-cert Depends openssl (>= 0.9.8g-9)
$ LANG=C aptitude why ssl-cert
i   cups Depends ssl-cert (>= 1.0.11)
```

(I used the LANG environment variable to get english output, not my local one).

I'm not sure but maybe rvm / gem do require the SSL development libraries, which are packaged into `libssl-dev`.

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

This is usually the case when you compile something from source, what gem as I remember does, when resolving package dependencies.

Comment: Is aptitude a package manager?

Comment: yes, see *"apt-get show aptitude"* for a description.

Comment: Ah-h-h `apt install libssl-dev` did it for me! Context: `gem update openssl` on Windows using Ubuntu on the subsystem (more context: Installing Jekyll). Gave very confusing error messages, wouldn't have figured it out. Thanks!!